# make each div have the same distance between each other using html?

Tags: html, css

i have this div class called 'answer_box', for each page thier will be 4  different answer boxes with different text each time. i want to make each answer have the same distance between each other, whether the box has a lot of text or little, to keep the design consistant.

my html code:

```
<div id="app">

    <div class="answer_box">
       <div class="answer_checkbox"></div>
       <span class="answers"> little bit of text</span>
    </div>

   <div class="answer_box">
       <div class="answer_checkbox"></div>
       <span class="answers">you have priotrtoities over the people on the opposite direction</span>
    </div>

    <div class="answer_box">
      <div class="answer_checkbox"></div>
      <span class="answers">you have priotrtoities over the people on the opposite direction</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/24E6W/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following CSS

```
.answer_box {
    margin-top: 20px;
    clear:both;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this 2 properties to your class named ".answer_box"

```
.answer_box{
margin-top: 20px;
border-top:1px solid #000000;
display:block;
clear:both;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Checkout jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/24E6W/1/)...

Answer (score 0):

Either set `min-height` on the `answer_box` div to cover the deepest box, or let jquery do it for you:

[using min-height (css only)](http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/vbLxG/2/)

[quick fiddle using jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/vbLxG/)

This will make the boxes the same height as the tallest one, the distance between each answer is set by the `margin-top:` rule. I'm assuming the `.answer_checkbox` div needs to be a consistent height

Answer (score 0):

Is this the effect you want? [jsfiddle.net/24E6W/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/24E6W/3/)

```
.answer_box {
margin:30px 0px;
height:50px;
}
.answer_checkbox {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: black;
float: left;
margin-right: 5px;

}
```